# Word for judgemental attitude?

Tags: single-word-requests

I'm tempted to use [judgementality](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/judgementality), which for whatever reason is not a word, and I don't feel like "judgement" conveys the same meaning.

> I was put off by his ________ towards my life choices.

If someone is stupid, they exhibit stupidity. If someone is judgemental, they exhibit ________.

Comment: Arbitrary?  It means pretty much "judgmental," even at the root: *arbiter*

Comment: judgementalism?

Comment: @KristinaLopez Yep, see update.

Comment: Please correct your spelling. There is no 'e' in *judgmental*. (Yes, I know, it makes no sense.)

Comment: @TimWard British/Canadian spelling is *judgemental*.

Comment: Interesting, because I find no evidence of that anywhere! The internet is so unreliable these days. And my teachers have failed me. I never once heard that the US had a unique spelling for this.

Comment: Apparently, the spelling with the 'e' is not the preferred spelling, no matter which side of the pond you're on... http://blog.dictionary.com/judgement-vs-judgment/

Comment: Although I don’t think you can ‘exhibit it,’ the gerund “[judging](http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=judging)” has been defined as “**The act of** looking down upon someone; to regard with contempt or disdain; to regard as an inferior,” and it would work in your first sentence's blank either by changing ‘towards’ to ‘of ' or by using it with no preposition at all: "I was put off by his **judging** [of] my life choices.".

Answer (score 7):

**judgmentalism** (no `e` on *judge*) or the less common *judgementalism*

Although the best definitions can only be found at [wiktionary](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/judgmentalism) (*judgmental behavior or attitude*) and a [Washington Times](http://www.washingtontimes.com/news/2009/sep/1/judgment-vs-judgmentalism/) article (quoted below), I think we will find this word in standard dictionaries soon enough.

> Opinion columnists, like the rest of humanity, walk a fine line between judgment (holding people accountable to a standard we did not create) and judgmentalism (thinking ourselves morally superior because we haven’t committed the acts of others).

[image]

<sub>*'judgmental behavior'* was almost bottomed out and the single word *'judgmental'* was off the chart. Both were removed. Note that with the extra `e`, both are on par with *judgmental behavior* (which is not found with the extra `e`) but *judgementalism* [still wins](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=judgmentalism%2Cjudgmental%20attitude%2Cjudgmental%20behavior%2Cjudgementalism%2Cjudgemental%20attitude%2Cjudgemental%20behavior&year_start=1900&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cjudgmentalism%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cjudgmental%20attitude%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cjudgmental%20behavior%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cjudgementalism%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cjudgemental%20attitude%3B%2Cc0).</sub>

Comment: "**The Mote and the Beam** (also called **discourse on judgmentalism**) is a proverbial saying of Jesus given in the Sermon on the Mount in the Gospel of Matthew, chapter 7, verses 1 thru 5." TFD

Answer (score 6):

The best single word for the attitude that finishes your sentence is ***criticism***.

The phrase you're looking for is ***judgmental attitude***.

> [Full Definition of **judgmental**](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/judgmental) 1 :  of, relating to, or involving
>   judgment **2 :  characterized by a tendency to judge harshly** <*judgmental
>   prigs*>

I'm not aware of a single word that means the same thing as *judgmental attitude*.

Interestingly, [Google Ngrams](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=judgmental%2Cjudgmental%20attitude&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cjudgmental%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cjudgmental%20attitude%3B%2Cc0) indicates that the use of "judgmental" is on a sharp rise, whereas "judgmental attitude" has only seen slight increase in the last few decades and is still a fraction of the overall usage of the term "judgmental".

Answer (score 2):

The problem you have here is that the noun ***judgement*** carries very good vibes. Having good judgement is seen as a positive attribute.

But its formed adjective ***judgemental*** is quite the reverse, with bad connotations.

Unless you are to coin another noun, on the back of an adjective formed from a noun, (heaven forbid) what you need is a near-synonym of ***judgement*** which is censorious and down-putting.

The best one I can come up with is ***pronouncements***, but you need to replace *towards* with *on*.

So how about ***His continual pronouncements on my life-choices were off-putting***

Comment: I actually don't think a synonym of judgement is what I'm looking for. I think the real problem with judgment is that it more so describes a specific "thing" that exists in concrete instances. One casts judgements. One makes a judgement. But does one exhibit judgement? If that works, fair enough I guess, though something about it feels clunky to me. Probably because of this duality it seems to feature. One exhibits stupidity for example, but one does not cast a stupidity.

Comment: @DrazenBjelovuk, neither does one cast a stupid...well, not conventionally anyhow. However, if you're looking for 'the state or quality of being judgemental', that's 'judgementalism'.

Comment: @DrazenBjelovuk, 'stupid' is an adj. and n. For the brief first part of the story, I'll refer you to Pitkin's approx. 600 pp. *A Short Introduction to the History of Human Stupidity*, the intro to a 27 volume partial history. In the section called "Psychagnoia" Pitkin mentions that "the normal man shows six stupid tendencies in judging other people". He lists the six and calls them "humanesque handicaps". Perhaps this is the term you seek?

Answer (score 1):

The first word that springs to my mind is *condescension*.

> I was put off by his condescension towards my life choices.

Clearly I'm suggesting the 2nd definition here

> ***Full Definition of condescension*** 1: voluntary descent from one's rank or dignity in relations with an inferior 2:  **patronizing attitude or behavior**

or even M-W's

> *Simple definition* : the attitude or behavior of people who believe they are more intelligent or better than other people

Edited to add:
Why ( I believe) it fits. In order to be judgmental, one must believe that their perspective/observations/conclusions about your life choices are superior to your own. I tend to use this term when I perceive the offender (in this sentence, the one doing the judging) is fully aware of their judgement and their belief that they are better/smarter than you - as though it was mixed with a tinge of haughtiness.

However...if, after coming out, your sweet little old granny sits you down and tells you that the Bible disagrees with your lifestyle choice and she believes it's wrong but she still loves you, it's still judgmental but I'm not sure it's strictly condescending.

Perhaps there is no English single-word solution that fits perfectly. What about *judgmental attitude*?

Comment: Welcome to English Language & Usage. This answer was flagged as low-quality because of its length and content. Can you try to include reference or link (that can support your answer) and its essential part? Please take the [tour](http://english.stackexchange.com/tour) and visit our [help center](http://english.stackexchange.com/help) for additional guidance.

Comment: This post would be improved with a dictionary definition, but otherwise I think it's pretty good.

Answer (score 0):

["Judgemental"](https://www.google.com/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=judgemental%20meaning) is really the word you are looking for. Unless we are talking of *creating* another word for it.

Examples:

> Judy this morning was being so judgemental on Robert's project. I wonder why.
>
> Some people are just way too judgemental and can't work on a high creative place where judgement-free is the usual norm.

In other words, "[judgement](https://www.google.com/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=judgement)" is the act or ability to make ponderated decisions or reaching conclusions. While "judgemental" is the adjective that you use to whom is being, well, judgemental, a ferocious critic, a person way contrary of yours or someone's point of view.

Comment: I'm looking for a noun that represents the act of being judgemental. "Judgemental" certainly doesn't fit the bill, and I feel like "judgement" refers more to a particular criticism than the essence of the act. If someone is stupid, they exhibit stupidity. If someone is judgemental, they exhibit _______.

Comment: So you want, for example, a noun that represents the act of being sad? This is called sadness. If you want the noun that represents the act of placing judgement too much, it is called being judgemental, there isn't another word for it that I'm aware of since the specific name of it is "judgemental", same way, the specific name of "feeling sad" is "sadness".

You might find though some synonyms in the vicinity of the meaning here: http://www.thesaurus.com/browse/judgmental

Comment: @DrazenBjelovuk I've heard the word "judging" used in that way, especially by people working in mental health.  I also found on something called www.urbandictionary.com the following: "The act of looking down upon someone; to regard with contempt or disdain; to regard as an inferior."  Your initial sentence would be reworded "I was put off by his judging of my life choices."

Comment: I edited your post. You can use `>` to denote blockquotes.

Comment: @DrazenBjelovuk, in Portuguese you have certain verbs that don't contain a specific form, they are called, by this reason, defective verbs. For them, we use verbal expressions. I'm not sure about the roots of the word "Judgemental", I might do some research on it, but it could be the same case here. No word like it, but a verbal expression that needs a helper, in this case, the verb "to be".

Answer (score 0):

**piety** is the first thing that comes to mind.  Piety is the state of being *pious*.

> **pious** *adj* deeply religious : devoted to a particular religion
>
> falsely appearing to be good or moral

Eg.

> I was put off by his *piety* in regard to my life choices.

Answer (score 0):

I voted for "criticism", but **reprobation** may fit.

> "reprobation" is between disapproval and condemnation.
>
> Example:  *Players faced a lot of criticism for their unsatisfactory performance and Ryan too was a target of this reprobation*.

Answer (score 0):

I get put off by people's **snooty** attitudes towards my lifestyle.

[Merriam Webster](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/snooty):

> ```
> 1:  looking down the nose :  showing disdain
> 2:  characterized by snobbery <a snooty store>
> ```

Answer (score 0):

I guess '**prejudiced attitude**' would suit you.

Prejudice is remarkably similar to its Latin root in form and meaning; the Latin prejudicium means "judgment in advance."

Answer (score 0):

*Reproval* is a good word. In your exemplar sentence, however, you would need to replace *towards* with *of*.

> I was put off by his reproval of my life choices.

Another--even stronger--word is *condemnatory*, but again, some word changes would be necessary, as in

> I was put off by his condemnatory attitude toward me and my life choices.

Or,

> I was put off by his condemnatory attitude about my life choices.

*Haughtiness* is also a possibility, as in

> I was put off by his haughtiness regarding my life choices.

Or,

> I was put off by his hauteur regarding my life choices.

And finally, I kind of like the words *smug* (adjective) and *smugness* (noun), each of which could be useful and apt.

> I was put off by his smugness regarding my life choices.

Or,

> I was put off by his smug attitude about my life choices.

And for good measure, here's another short list of possibilities:

> - arrogance
> - disdain
> - contempt
> - loftiness
> - superciliousness
> - contemptuousness